# How to perform a room transaction usin Rxjava

Tags: android, transactions, rx-java, android-room

How can I do a room transaction across 2 different DAOs usin rxjava?

I have this code that I would like to use with Rxjava  but I need it to return some kind of observable

```
 @Transaction
fun insertStoreWithPictures(store: Store, pictures: List<StorePicture>) {

    insertStore(store)
    insertPictures(pictures)

}
```

The store DAO

```
@Dao
abstract public class store {

@Insert
Single<Long> insert(store  entity);
}
```

The storePicture DAO

```
@Dao
abstract public class storePicture {

    @Insert
    Completable insert(storePicture... entity);
}
```

Comment: check the second example in this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction

Comment: The exanple is for a select transaction. I need to perform a transaction for an insert that uses 2 different DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `zip` or `combine` operator of `RxJava`. It would create an observable from an iterators observable source.

Answer (score 0):

Best example you can follow to achieve the same - https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-zip-operator-with-example

Comment: Does the zip operator do a rollback if there is an error in the transaction?

Comment: @Shura What exactly is your requirement? I mean if you are asking if there is an error in any of the API calls, yes it will throw an error in common error handler callback.

Comment: My requirement is to make a database transaction. If one of the operations gives an error it should rollback all the database changes done until then. Does zip garantee that? Or it just gives an error but the succefull changes to the database are maintained?

Comment: that is something you need to implement in your error callback, I doubt Rx will provide you that